# Display a field using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with a field in with data such as:

```
id | path
1  | /2/9/1 
2  | /2/4/11 
3  | /1/3/11 
4  | /5/3/2 
5  | /2/1/4
```

I'm wanting to do a select query to show only the first number between the slashes.  Can you use a Regex in the select part of a query?  If so, what is the syntax to find what I need?

Comment: Is the number always 0-9? If so, there's easy ways of doing this

Comment: Its always a number, but more than likely it will be something like /143/23/153

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function for that, no need for regexes:

```
   SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', 2), '/', -1)
```

Comment: I get the error message 1582: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'  Its fine when I put an actual string in there but trying to do it on a field errors

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Show us the exact query you run.

Comment: SELECT substring_index( substring_index(cc.path),'/',2),'/',-1) as path FROM mdl_course_categories as cc;

Comment: The "incorrect parameter count" indicates that you missed a comma or you misplaced parentheses and that's what you did. There is an extra parenthesis after `cc.path`. Remove it.

Comment: Thats sorted it.  Cheers